# Waterfall prompt using activity.text instead of actually prompting user

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have a dialog where a prompt in the first step is getting skipped. I determined that what is happening is that somehow step.context.activity.text is automatically being interpreted as the prompt response. For example, if I trigger the dialog with "Expedite my order", step.context.activity.text in the first step is "Expedite my order", the prompt is skipped, and step.result in the next step is "Expedite my order".

I tried creating a "buffer step" as step 1 that just did `return await step.next()`, but the same activity.text was then captured as the prompt response in step 2!

Interestingly, I created a mock dialog test with mocha and it did NOT exhibit these issues. I have other dialogs within the bot that also have a text prompt on step one and they are not exhibiting these issues either in mocha tests OR running in emulator (or deployed on Azure). I did note there is one difference within step.context: the dialogs that are working have `step.context.responded = false` and the one which is skipping the prompt has step.context.responded = true`. But I have no idea why this is set in one case but not others. This seems to be an important part of the puzzle.

I did "solve" this by setting `step.context.activity.text = ''` at the beginning of the step, but that seems like a bad practice. Any idea on why this is happening within this prompt? Below is my dialog code through that first step.

```js
const { TextPrompt, ChoicePrompt, ChoiceFactory, ComponentDialog, WaterfallDialog } = require('botbuilder-dialogs');
const { oemLocatorHelper } = require('../helpers/oemLocatorHelper');

const WATERFALL_DIALOG = 'waterfallDialog2';
const CHOICE_PROMPT = 'choicePrompt';
const TEXT_PROMPT = 'textPrompt';
const ESCALATION_OPTIONS = ['Chat','Email','Call','No Thanks'];

class escalationDialog extends ComponentDialog {
    constructor(dialogId, userDialogStateAccessor, userState) {
        super(dialogId);

        this.addDialog(new ChoicePrompt(CHOICE_PROMPT));
        this.addDialog(new TextPrompt(TEXT_PROMPT));
        this.addDialog(new WaterfallDialog(WATERFALL_DIALOG, [
            this.promptAccount.bind(this),
            this.promptChannel.bind(this),
            this.promptSummary.bind(this)
        ]));

        this.initialDialogId = WATERFALL_DIALOG;

        // State accessors
        this.userDialogStateAccessor = userDialogStateAccessor;
        this.userState = userState;

    } // End constructor

    async promptAccount(step) {
        if (step.context.responded) {
            step.context.activity.text = '';
        }
        const userData = await this.userDialogStateAccessor.get(step.context, {});
        if (userData.accountNumber) {
            return userData.accountNumber;
        } else {
            return await step.prompt(TEXT_PROMPT, `To help me get you to the right agent, can you please provide me your account number?`);
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Should be step.context.activity.text, not step.activity.text. Updated in several spots. Also, the change now clears this value only if step.context.responded is true.

Comment: I presume when you say step.activity.text you mean step.context.activity.text. What version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: Yes, step.context.activity.text. I'll correct it in my question. Using nodejs v4.

Comment: Also, I now am clearing that value only if step.context.responded is true and it is working, so it seems it's definitely that value that is causing the issue, but I don't know how it's getting set in the first place.

Comment: 4.4? 4.5? 4.6? 4.7?

Comment: This looks like buggy behavior. Does the issue persist when you update to the latest version of the Bot Builder packages?

Comment: 4.5.3. I'll update and see what happens.

Comment: At 4.7 now and problem persists. I'm also having some (likely) related issues where dialog is ending after a prompt for no reason (responded value is false in these cases and clearing activity.text doesn't help. I've also commented out all endDialog lines and something is still causing the dialog to cancel).

Comment: @KyleDelaney, I cloned this to github and invited you, I think there's too much code and too much going on to try to continue the discussion here. You can reach out to me further through github or at my Eaton email address. Would appreciate any review and insight you can offer here. I opened an issue on the github repo with repro steps in case you want to run locally (though not recommended, there are a lot of .env variables that it will want to have...).

Comment: Would you link me to the GitHub issue?

Comment: https://github.com/Tiger519/Order_Status_Bot/issues/1

Comment: OK, I solved the dialog issue. I wasn't using `return` on my dialog push. I'm not sure why it only failed in the middle of the newly pushed dialog, but so far my tests are indicating that returning the beginDialog statement has fixed it. The issue with the prompt taking activity.text instead of waiting for user response still persists, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that your bot class is calling `continueDialog` on the same turn that it begins `escalationDialog`. I have commented on your private GitHub issue.

Comment: I will check it out. Following the interruption (and continueDialog) code, there is also an `if (!dc.context.responded)` statement before the switch blocks, so it definitely appears there is a relation between this and what I'm seeing when the prompt is skipped. Will check and report back.

Comment: @billoverton - Are you going to upvote and accept this answer?

Comment: Just tested and confirmed this was the issue. I modified the interrupt function to return true even when new dialogs are starting and REMOVED the reprompt for all interrupts (which is why I initially returned false for new dialogs). Instead, I'm reprompting only the required dialogs (Help) from inside isTurnInterrupted, doing nothing if `true` is returned, and calling `continueDialog` if `false` is returned.