# My dialog does not wait for user response in Bot Framework v4

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-bot-service

I have 2 classes:

1. **RootDialog**
2. **QualificationDialog**

My Bot starts with **RootDialog**, where I make the call to the LUIS service and based on the result I direct it to a method for each intention.

In this case I am going to a method called "**IntentQualify**", within this method I am calling the following "**QualificationDialog**" dialog that contains **SuggestionAction** buttons integrated in a **WaterfallDialog**, the WaterfallSteps contains 2 methods that should be executed sequentially:

**The first (ToShowButton):** Shows the buttons.

**The second (ValidateOption):** Captures the user's selection based on the buttons.

The problem is that at the moment of showing the buttons, it does not generate a wait, it does not go to the 2 method (**ValidateOption**) it goes out and the conversation ends.

Anyone who has been through this case who can help me?

**FIRST DIALOGUE**

```
public class RootDialog : ComponentDialog
{
        public RootDialog(ILuisService luisService)
        {
            _luisService = luisService;
            AddDialog(new TextPrompt(nameof(TextPrompt)));
        }
        public override async Task<DialogTurnResult> BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, object options = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var luisResult = await _luisService._recognizer.RecognizeAsync(dc.Context, cancellationToken);
            await ManageIntentions(dc, luisResult, cancellationToken);
            return await dc.EndDialogAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }
        private async Task ManageIntentions(DialogContext dc, RecognizerResult luisResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var topIntent = luisResult.GetTopScoringIntent();
            switch (topIntent.intent)
            {                
                case "Qualify":
                    await IntentQualify(dc, luisResult, cancellationToken);
                    break;
                case "None":
                    await IntentNone(dc, luisResult, cancellationToken);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        private async Task IntentQualify(DialogContext dc, RecognizerResult luisResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Here I call the second dialog (ss) that contains the buttons and 
            // should generate the wait but does not.
            dc.Dialogs.Add(new QualificationDialog());
            await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(QualificationDialog), null, cancellationToken);
        }


}
```

**SECOND DIALOGUE**

```
public class QualificationDialog: ComponentDialog
    {
        public QualificationDialog()
        {
            var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                ToShowButton,
                ValidateOption
            };
            AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), waterfallSteps));
            AddDialog(new TextPrompt(nameof(TextPrompt)));
        }
        public static async Task<DialogTurnResult> ToShowButton(DialogContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
                  nameof(TextPrompt),
                  new PromptOptions
                  {
                      Prompt = CreateButtonsQualification()
                  },
                  cancellationToken
            );
        }
        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ValidateOption(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var options = stepContext.Context.Activity.Text;
            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }
        public static Activity CreateButtonsQualification()
        {
            var reply = MessageFactory.Text("MY TEXT");

            reply.SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions()
            {
                Actions = new List<CardAction>()
                {
                    new CardAction(){Title = "OPTION 1", Value = "OPTION 1", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack},
                    new CardAction(){Title = "OPTION 2", Value = "OPTION 2", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack},
                    new CardAction(){Title = "OPTION 3", Value = "OPTION 3", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack}
                }
            };
            return reply as Activity;
        }
```

**Class that implements IBot**

```
public class MyBot<T> : ActivityHandler where T: Dialog
    {
        BotState _conversationState;
        BotState _userState;
        Dialog _dialog;

        public MyBot(ConversationState conversationState, UserState userState, T dialog)
        {
            _conversationState = conversationState;
            _userState = userState;
            _dialog = dialog;
        }

        protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            foreach (var member in membersAdded)
            {
                if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                {
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Hello world!"), cancellationToken);
                }
            }
        }

        public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
            await _conversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
            await _userState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);

        }
        protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await _dialog.RunAsync(
              turnContext,
              _conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)),
              cancellationToken
            );
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you share the Class with implements IBot.

Comment: Are you basing you bot on core-bot sample? I had a similar issue that was related to incorrectly calling continueDialog immediately after beginDialog. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59385126/waterfall-prompt-using-activity-text-instead-of-actually-prompting-user

Comment: @ChithambaraKumar add the class that implements IBot -->MyBot.

Answer (score 1):

In your RootDialog , you are calling EndDialogAsync as soon you as begin the QualificationDialog in BeginDialogAsync method. Since are you ending the parent dialog all the child dialogs of the parent in the stack are removed. You can rewrite the method as below and check if it is working and try the end the root dialog gracefully in some-other intent

`public override async Task<DialogTurnResult> BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, object options = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var luisResult = await _luisService._recognizer.RecognizeAsync(dc.Context, cancellationToken);
           return  await ManageIntentions(dc, luisResult, cancellationToken); 
        }`.